# Fatal Error AFTER text change listener executed

Tags: android

### SOLVED

I have an app that searches through an arraylist whenever the search string is updated in an EditText.
I have a text change listener added to the EditText. It usually works but randomly I've been getting a Fatal error with no reference to a line number in my app (I'm Using Eclipse Logcat)
I've put log outputs in my code to find the last line that is executed. Unexpectedly this turned out to be AFTER the text change listener had executed all it's code, and presumably after the thread had been handed back to the UI?
I'd be grateful of any help.

Here's the full code in my text Listener. I'm getting the log output saying it Finished this function though. So where does the thread go after this?

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (("" + inputField.getText()).length() > 0) {
                fullSearchString += ("" + inputField.getText()).trim();
                inputField.setText("");
                searchArray(fullSearchString);
                out("FINISHED Text change Listener");
            }
        }
```

Here's the stack trace

```
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6194)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6377)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:897)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:257)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
09-21 13:05:24.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7660):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Whatever you are doing in your listener is trying to access index 1, when it only has the zeroth element (meaning it only has one element). What might cause this? Post your code

Comment: thanks, added the code, the searchArray() function is very lengthy and  apparently isn't what's causing the problem...maybe?

Comment: That could be it, please post that method and maybe the example string you are using.

Comment: SOLVED (Sorry don't have rep to answer my own questions yet) I discovered the cause of the problem, under some situations my text change listener is being added TWICE! since the first instance of the listener changes the EditText contents the second one causes a fatal exception. (Still not sure why but it doesn't matter!)
It's something that happened to me before with dynamically adding listeners. I should have learnt the first time!